# create separate Django admin panel

Tags: python, django, session, authentication, django-admin

I couldn't find the answer to my questions after hours of research!
is it possible to create completely separate admin panel in Django?
how authentication works on Django?! on a user control panel for example
how to control sessions and let user log in into the panel etc.
what is the correct way to use NOSQL DB's like Mongodb as backend for Django?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you take the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/) and go through the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/). It is very extensive and it covers your questions. But it will take more than a few hours.

Here are some pointers to get you started:

- Yes, you can write your own admin panel. If you don't want to use the built-in admin you can simply write a back-end where an authenticated user can add and edit content. You simply implement the authentication system manually and make all pages within this back-end only accessible to registered users. References:

[Authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/)

Simply build an authentication form and in your view do something like this:

```
def login(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('/admin')
    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/login')
```

Then in your views you simply add the [login_required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) to protect pages:

```
@login_required
def index(request):
    articles = Article.objects.order_by('name')
    context = { 'aarticles' : articles }
    return render(request, 'admin/homepage.html', context)
```

And here is a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMgF3JwKzgs) on how to log users in.

To use MongoDB there are several options. You can use [Djongo](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/) which is a "Django and MongoDB connector" and allows you to use MongoDB like any other database system. Alternatively you can follow [this tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-django-mongo/index.html), but if you integrate MongoDB like this you will lose the regular admin panel (perhaps that's why you were wondering about how to go about this instead).

Good luck!